# Inference algorithm of Shenoy and Shafer

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, bayesian-networks

I have heard of this algorithm, but is this algorithm good to use it with Bayesian Belief networks? Hugin is based on it and I'm looking for a book / article on this algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't kept track of this research area for a while, but I can point you towards the
CiteSeerX search engine if you don't know it already. (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/)

Searching for [papers which cite Shenoy & Shafer's *An axiomatic framework for Bayesian and belief function propagation (1990)*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/showciting?cid=994706) will give you a list of other researchers who have tried to apply the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is described in this [paper](http://www.glennshafer.com/assets/downloads/articles/article43.pdf). It is quite detailed and should be a good point to start.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the algorithm but another place to check for information would be 
[a search in google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Inference+algorithm+of+Shenoy+and+Shafer&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=2001&as_sdtp=on/).

Answer (score 1):

**[Pulcinella](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/pulcinella/Welcome.html)** is a tool for Propagating Uncertainty through Local Computations based on the general framework af valuation systems proposed by **Shenoy and Shafer**

> Pulcinella is freely available for
>   educational and strictly
>   non-commercial use. Pulcinella is
>   written in Common Lisp. It has been
>   tested on Allegro CL on Macintosh, and
>   on Lucid CL, Allegro CL, and CLisp on
>   a Sun. The code is just "pure" common
>   lisp, so it should also run on any
>   other reasonable implementation of
>   common-lisp (well, you know...). To
>   get the latest version, click here.
>   Alternatively, you can get Pulcinella
>   by anonymous ftp from
>   ftp://aass.oru.se/pub/saffiotti. The
>   Pulcinella tar archive includes a few
>   examples, taken from the User's
>   Manual. If you fetch this program, you
>   are expected to send a letter at the
>   address below, stating that you will
>   use Pulcinella for research and
>   non-commercial use only.

Also [here](http://www.roseindia.net/linux/tutorial/linux-howto/AI-Alife-HOWTO-3.html) is some references.

**Even More references:**

[An Algorithm for Bayesian Belief Network Construction from Data](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~jcheng/Doc/aistat97.pdf)

[A Tutorial on Learning With Bayesian Networks](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69588/tr-95-06.pdf)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#External_links